# Getting the column type from a raw SQL statement for reporting purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, reporting

I'm building a generalized reporting tool for rails, and I'd like to not only get the column names of a raw SQL query, but the converted ruby type as well. I'm going to use the type to make the interface a little better.

The following works, but surely there's a more "rails"-way to approach this? The query is just an example, it could potentially span every table using whatever dynamic SQL the user wants.

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE"
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.exec(sql)
    results.nfields.times do |i|
      puts results.fname(i)
      name = results.fname(i)
      typename = DataSet.connection.raw_connection.
        exec( "SELECT format_type($1,$2)", [results.ftype(i), results.fmod(1)] ).
        getvalue( 0, 0 )
      column = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name, nil, typename)
      puts column.klass # gives a decent assumption of type
    end
```

Comment: The best I could come up with so far is above.

Answer (score -1):

`ModelX.columns.each do |column|
  puts column.sql_type # int(11)
  puts column.type # :integer
end`

This assumes you have an ActiveRecord model for each table.